# Does Bitly v3 shorten API work?

Tags: api, rest, oauth-2.0, bit.ly

Does anybody have a working example of [Bitly's V3 API](http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation#/v3/shorten) working?

The Oauth seems to work but [shorten](http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation#/v3/shorten) always returns:

```
{data=[], status_code=500, status_txt=MISSING_ARG_APIKEY}
```

Even if I supply the apiKey (which I shouldn't have to if I'm using the access_token) I still get the error.
I have tried both the SSL and non SSL endpoint. The V2 api works fine for me though.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. it works.

Example:

```
http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten?format=txt&login=$username$&apiKey=$key$&longUrl=$longurl$
```

you can get `username` and `api key` from [`here`](https://bitly.com/a/account). For username, there's a section named `Public Timeline` where there will be links like `https://bitly.com/u/o_19rtfe2ph0` and `https://bitly.com/u/o_19rtfe2ph0.rss`. Here `o_19rtfe2ph0` is the username to be used.

Hope it helps. [Here's the full documentation](http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation#/v3/shorten).

Comment: it works now. It did not work when I was using it. They must have had a service outage or something that day.,

Answer (score 0):

If you were trying the thing using curl via command line and were not quoting the url, then the first ampersand meant to be an argument separator actually executed what you had typed so far in the background, thus breaking the whole thing.

Simple answer for that, quote the whole url string and it should work.